# Some Font Awesome Icons Not Showing Up

Tags: html, font-awesome

For some reason some of my font awesome icons are not showing up in my website that I am currently building. Any idea what is wrong here? I have learned that there was a bug that may have been the problem and have tried a number of different link tags in my HTML header pointing to the font awesome library, but still nothing...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackOverflow. Could you please edit the question to add debugging details? c.f. the help article [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 4.7 isn't the current version. Are you maybe using icons that aren't in your version?

Comment: @RoToRa That is very possible. How would I go about getting the link to the library with the icon versions I am using...

Comment: Have you tried the the [Font Awesome website](https://fontawesome.com/)?